# ¿Como reordenar este array?

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
$array_atual = array (
    'id_item' => array('1', '3'), // 'id_item', 'id_item'
    'cantidad' => array('15', '10') // 'cantidad', 'cantidad'
);
```

Quisiera saber como podria dejarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$array_final (
    '0' => array('1', '15'); // 'id_item', 'cantidad'
    '1' => array('3', '10')     // 'id_item', 'cantidad'
);
```

¿Como podria hacer este cambio?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Con qué problemas/dificultades te estás encontrando?

Answer (score 1):

suponiendo que tienes la misma cantidad de elementos dentro de los array de `id_item y cantidad` tendrías que ciclar uno de los dos, con eso tendrías las posiciones que corresponde uno de cada uno, y solo las agregas a otro arreglo temporal.

Espero te sirva

```
$arr = array(
    'id_item' => array(1,2,3,4,5),
    'cantidad' => array(10,20,30,40,50)
);

$newArr = array();
for( $i = 0; $i < count($arr['id_item']); $i++ ){
   $newArr[] = array( $arr['id_item'][$i], $arr['cantidad'][$i] );
}

print_r($newArr);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar a la solución de Alberto, pero con un un forEach:

```
$array_atual = array (
    'id_item' => array('1', '3'), // 'id_item', 'id_item'
    'cantidad' => array('15', '10') // 'cantidad', 'cantidad'
);

$array_final = array();

forEach($array_atual as $array) {
    forEach($array as $key=>$value) {

        if (!array_key_exists($key, $array_final)) {
            $array_final[$key] = array();
        }

        array_push($array_final[$key], $value);

    }
}
```

Comment: Me parece una mejor solución. Además **no es dependiente de las llaves `id_item, cantidad`**. O sea, si agregas un tercer sub-array también lo combinaría del modo esperado.

Comment: Me alegra que te guste. Exactamente eso intenté conseguir, y honestamente terminó siendo un reto mayor de lo que esperaba.
Saludos Cedano, no dejo de admirar la solución que me diste con el fetch_object, excelente.